# Delete all subdirectories in a directory except for one

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to delete all subdirectories within `%path%` except for the subdirectory `foobar`, using a batch file:

```
for /D %%d in ("%path%\*") do if NOT "%%d" == "foobar" rd /S /Q "%%d"
```

However, all subdirectories in `%path%` are being deleted, including `foobar`.
What can be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it from the command line.

```
for /d %I in ("path\*") do @echo %I
```

Notice any clues?  `path\` is prepended to all results; and therefore, `"path\foobar"` will never equal `"foobar"`.

Try the `%%~nxI` trick to get the leaf of the path.

```
for /d %%d in ("path\*") do if not "%%~nxd"=="foobar" rd /q /s "%%d"
```

Also, use a different variable name for your path.  `%PATH%` already has special meaning, and you'll have problems if you step on its toes.

Comment: Ha, that was it. Didn't even think about the path being included. Thank you very much.